# Showing related entries field

Tags: entries, relations, entries-field

I have a section called Services. I have another section called Case Studies.

For each Case Study I want to show which service is being used so I add an entry field and choose the right service. On my case study I can see that the service is showing as it should.

On the Service page I want to see which case studies are being associated with the Service.

Comment: Can you expand your question slightly to explain what you are viewing and what you are trying to show? It sounds like you're trying to show a field from one entry on another entry's page? You also mention that you are already showing A on X?

Comment: Ok, say I have a section called Services. I have another section called Case Studies. 

For each Case Study I want to show which service is being used so I add an entry field and choose the right service. On my case study I can see that the service is showing as it should. All good til there.

But I want that on the Service page I can see which case studies are being associated with this Service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your Case Study has a field called `services` which is an entry relation. You show the services on that Case Study page using

```
// entry is the current Case Study
{% set related_services = craft.entries.section( 'services' ).relatedTo( entry ) %}
```

To show all Case Studies that are related to a Service you can use the same entries query.

```
// entry is the current Service
{% set related_case_studies = craft.entries.section( 'caseStudies' ).relatedTo( entry ) %}
```